# SQL Server stored procedure parameters-DIFFERENT types

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

By developing app. I need a  dynamic stored procedure, where I am calling a table name (@pxxx), and I also ned pass same parameters - here I have 2 (datum, por). 
It is working well, passing tablename as @pxxx - o.k. Also when parameters  datum,por are type -int or varchar, or char or combination of it. Int I change to varchar by CONVERT - procedure go well. Well ig going calling from C#.
Problem is when I change parameter -datum to **datetime**. It is not working. Changing date by "convert" to varchar not helped. It is not functional in sql management studio. I need to solve a problem, because I need in table datum [datetime], 
I can't change table definition, **datetime is needed.**
I looked for almost every questions about passing parameters and dynamic sql stored procedures, but I not find solution.

Table definition in MS SQL 2005:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[p001](
   [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [datum] [datetime] NULL,
   [por] [int] NULL,
   [cas] [nchar](5) NULL,
   [max] [int] NULL,
   [obsad] [int] NULL,
   [blok] [bit] NULL
   one of it ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My stored procedure  -  **not working**

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPinsertpxx2] (@pxxx nchar(4),@date datetime, @por int) 
 AS
  DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(500)
  SET @sqlCommand =  'INSERT INTO '+ @pxxx +' ([datum],[por]) VALUES('
  +CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date,112)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@por,5)+')'
  BEGIN
  EXEC (@sqlCommand)
  END
```

This stored procedure  -  **working well**  but only withous datetime parameter.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPinsertpxxx] (@pxxx nchar(4),@cas nvarchar(10), @por int) 
AS
 DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(500)
 SET @sqlCommand =  'INSERT INTO '+ @pxxx +' ([cas],[por]) VALUES('
 +CONVERT(VARCHAR,@cas)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@por)+')'
    BEGIN
     EXEC (@sqlCommand)
    END
```

Comment: not helped, so 114, or changing language to british.

Comment: Error msg>failed when converting datetime from character string.
I read samewhere that in dynamic sql comand must be string(varchar). And every parameter therefore I convert by CONVERT(VARCHAR,@parameter), it helped for int, but not datetime

Comment: You have a couple of issues going on here. First you should be parameterizing your dynamic sql to help prevent sql injection. Also you are converting to varchar but don't specify a length. My question is if you are inserting into a datetime column why are you passing a varchar? You also need to define "not working". What does that mean?

Comment: Because if I change in alter procedure to "@datum datetime", I get an error.

Comment: How about you share the error message instead of making us guess? My guess is if you used parameterized dynamic sql the error would no longer happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of doing this using parameterzied dynamic sql. This helps prevent sql injection and allows you to use properly typed parameters.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPinsertpxx2] 
(
    @pxxx nchar(4)
    , @datum datetime
    , @por int
) AS
    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)

    SET @sqlCommand =  'INSERT INTO '+ @pxxx +' ([datum],[por]) VALUES(@datum, @por)'

    exec sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@datum datetime, @por int', @datum = @datum, @por = @por
```

Now to test this and see if it works.

```
exec SPinsertpxx2 'p001', '2016-01-01', 42
```

Does the table contain the correct values?

```
select * from p001
```

Comment: Now working.  After restarting ...  Thank you very much.